# java-Declaring Array Based on If Statement

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement

I was wondering if there is any way to declare an array of different sizes depending on if an if statement condition is met. However, after typing in this code into NetBeans:

```
if(winner == true)
    double data[][] = new double[16][5];
else
    double data[][] = new double[14][5];
```

I receive an error message stating: Variable declaration not allowed here.

Why is this not allowed? Is there any way to accomplish what I am trying to do?
Tia.

**NOTE**

As was made clear in the answers provided, I was not considering scope when writing this post. I apologize. Thanks to everyone who provided helpful solutions and insight.

Comment: declare the reference outside the if and initialize it inside

Comment: the issue is that you have a single lined code scope that declares and assigns a scope local variable. That variable will fall out of scope immediately after you set it, so the IDE assumes you made some mistake.

Comment: You can also: `double data[][] = new double[winner? 16 : 14][5];`

Comment: Can someone elaborate as to why I am getting down voted for this?

Comment: Because your code makes obivously not a single bit of sense. What do you expect to do with a variable which will be removed after the if/else block?

Comment: @Tom Ok, I understand. I honestly wasn't thinking when I wrote this snippet of code. I should have considered scope.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

An alternative solution would be:

```
double data[][] = new double[winner ? 16 : 14][5];
```

The `x ? a : b` thing is called a "ternary operator". It evaluates to `a` if `x` is true, otherwise `b`.

Answer (score 5):

You should do :

```
double data[][]; 
if(winner == true)  // or just --> if (winner)
    data = new double[16][5];
else
   data = new double[14][5];
```

Essentially, when you declare it in the if, you can only use it in the if. It's scope is limited to that if.

Answer (score 2):

The Arrays you declare are inside an if function where they arent used again, im not sure if thats the reason for your error but maybe declare the var outside the IF statement

```
double data[][];

if(winner == true){
    data = new double[16][5];
}else{
    data = new double[14][5];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to declare your array outside your `if..else` block and initialize it inside your `if..else` blocks:

```
double data[][];

if(winner == true)
    data = new double[16][5];
else
    data = new double[14][5];
```

Comment: If you want to be paranoid, it's certainly because one of the other posters isn't fairplay and wants his own solution to be above yours ! Honestly I'd suggest deleting your answer which doesn't provide more than the 3 above, getting rid of the downvote in the process. I suggest it to you because you've got the downvote, but I totally agree all these answers are equal ; it's just stupid to see the same answer 3 times

Comment: Could it be because of the brackets during assignment? I get unexpected token on the declaration lines. If I change `data[][] = new double[16][5];` to `data = new double[16][5];` it goes through fine.

Comment: oh yes this is maybe the reason its my bad i already fix it @DanielBarbarian thank you for the help

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to declare a variable inside an `if` block because it will be out of scope as soon as you exit that block.  Declare the variable before the `if`, then initialize it inside.

```
double data[][];

if(winner == true)
    data = new double[16][5];
else
    data = new double[14][5];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
double data[][];
if(winner)
     data = new double[16][5];
else
     data = new double[14][5];
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside if statement only statements are allowed, but A declaration is not a statement, so it's not allowed in that spot.

Ok, just try in this way;

```
double data[][];
if(winner)
   data=new double[16][5];
else
   data=new double[14][5];
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a perfect opportunity to use a ternary operator.

```
double data[][] = (isWinner)?new double[16][5] : new double[14][5];
```

**Suggestions**

- Name your boolean variable `isWinner` instead of `winner` and you can 
  perform the check like the example above. By removing the condition 
  `winner == true` your code becomes easier to read.
- Use the [ternary operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html), it makes your code shorter and clearer to read.

Answer (score -2):

It's an old corner cases, add curly braces as you always should:

```
        if(winner == true) {
            double data[][] = new double[16][5];
        }
        else {
            double data[][] = new double[14][5];
        }
```

This is due to the fact that you statements are local variable declaration statements. This behaviour is described in Java Puzzlers and it's covered in the JLS section 14.4.

Comment: There won't be any error anymore, but the error was there for a good reason

Comment: So instead of fixing the error, you prefer to "hide" it? Clever.

Comment: @Aaron and what is the error ? I thinks it'a miss understood feature of the language, as it's covered by the JLS in section 14.4. Here is the part from Java Puzzlers: A local variable declaration looks like a statement but technically speaking is not; it is a local variable declaration statement [JLS 14.4].

Comment: @Tom please check my above comment and rethink your "clever" part.

Comment: Your code makes as less sense as OPs code, because you ___still___ create a useless variable.

Comment: The error is that declaring a variable as the only "statement" of a block is totally useless since it will be out-of-scope and garbaged collected just after having been created. The not-exactly-a-statement property of variable declaration prevents you from doing this mistake with single line then/else blocks, which you can avoid by using brackets, but you'll still be declaring a dead variable

Comment: @Aaron depends on the use case, maybe he just wants to hurt the GC. His question was strictly about the compilation error, this is what I wanted to answer to.

Comment: @comanitza I thought you had a point, but OP's first sentence clearly states that he want to declare an array of variable size depending on a condition. That makes me assume he will want to use this array afterward, and people downvoting you probably found this obvious too.

Comment: I still think your point is interesting though, just probably not the solution OP is looking for ; I'd add it as a comment if I were you